# Sort a crontab based on frequency of execution

Tags: cron

I have the output from crontab -l containing about 1500 lines.
I need to sort them based on the frequency of execution.

I tried a Perl module named Crontab::Interval but it didn't seem to accept jobs written with interval, that is * 4-20 * * *.

The goal is to identify all jobs that run more than once every hour.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to try to filter using `awk` pattern matching logic.

Print only lines that: `Field#1` not match `*` **AND**  `Field#2` not match `*`

```
crontab -l| awk '$1 !~ /\*/ && $2 !~ /\*/ 1'| sort
```